# Replacing an item in an Object array with null (java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, null

I'm starting to learn object orientation in my course and we have an object class called `students`. An object of the `students`class stores the instance variables: `studentName`, `studentNumber`, and `studentGPA`. I have a boolean method in my object class that determines whether the student is a failing student or not (the student is failing if their GPA is > 2.0) and then I have a method in my worker class that is supposed to accept the array of `students` objects, and then if the student is failing, it replaces that object with "null".

My problem is that I'm having a hard time replacing the students objects with null, since java keeps throwing me  or some such. Here's what I've tried:

```
public static void removeFailingStudents(Student[] students)
 {
  int count;

  for (count=0; count<students.length; count++)
  {
    if(students[count].isFailing())
    {
      students[count] = null;
    } 
  }
 }
```

and

```
public static void removeFailingStudents(Student[] students)
 {
  int count;

  for (count=0; count<students.length; count++)
  {
    if(students[count].isFailing())
    {
      students[count] = "null";
    } 
  }
 }
```

but when I compile/run these attempts it either throws me an exception or it yells at me because it is not of the type `Student`. How do I set an item in an array of objects to null?? Thanks for the help!

Here's my full code:

```
public class L2Q1
{
 public static void main(String[] parms)
 {
  process();

  System.out.println("\nEnd of processing.");
 }

 public static void process()
 {
  Student[] students;
  Student[] newStudents;

  students = getStudents();
  printStudents(students);
  printAverageGPA(students);
  printHonourStudents(students);
  removeFailingStudents(students);
  printStudents(students);
  newStudents = compactStudents(students);
  printStudents(students);
  printStudents(newStudents);
 }

 public static void printStudents(Student[] students)
 {
  int count;

  System.out.println("Students:");
  for (count=0; count<students.length; count++)
  {
    System.out.println(students[count].toString());
  }
  System.out.println();
 }

 public static void printAverageGPA(Student[] students)
 {
  double sumGPA;
  int count;

  sumGPA = 0;
  for (count=0; count<students.length; count++)
  {
    sumGPA += students[count].getGPA();  
  }
  double average = sumGPA / count;
  System.out.println("The average GPA is " + average);
  System.out.println();
 }

 public static void printHonourStudents(Student[] students)
 {
  int count;

  System.out.println("Honour students:");
  for (count=0; count<students.length; count++)
  {
    if(students[count].isHonourStudent())
    {
      System.out.println(students[count].toString());
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
 }

 public static void removeFailingStudents(Student[] students)
 {
  int count;

  for (count=0; count<students.length; count++)
  {
    if(students[count].isFailing())
    {
      students[count] = null;
    } 
  }
 }

 public static Student[] compactStudents(Student[] students)
 {
  Student[] newStudents;
  int count1;
  int count2;

  System.out.println("Compacting failing students.");
  System.out.println();
  count1 = 0;
  for (count2=0; count2<students.length; count2++)
  {

  }

  newStudents = new Student[0];
  return newStudents;
 }

 public static Student[] getStudents()
 {
  Student[] students = new Student[]
  {
   new Student(7654321, "Lara Zhivago", 3.75),
   new Student(7654322, "Betty Brown", 1.9),
   new Student(7654323, "Chris Cross", 0.5),
   new Student(7654324, "Dr. Dre", 4.0),
   new Student(7654325, "Joe Cool", 2.0)
  };

  return students;
 }
}

/******************************************************************/
/******************************************************************/

class Student
{
  private int number;
  private String name;
  private double gpa;

  public Student(int snum, String sname, double sgpa)
  {
    this.number = snum;
    this.name = sname;
    this.gpa = sgpa;

  }

  public double getGPA()
  {
    return gpa;
  }

  public boolean isHonourStudent()
  {
    boolean isHonourStudent = false;
    if(getGPA() >= 3.5)
    {
      isHonourStudent = true;
    }
    return isHonourStudent;
  }

  public boolean isFailing()
  {
    boolean isFailing = false;
    if(getGPA() < 2.0)
    {
      isFailing = true;
    }
    return isFailing;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return  number + " " + name + " " + gpa;
  }
}
```

Here's the exception message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at L2Q1.printStudents(L2Q1.java:41)
    at L2Q1.process(L2Q1.java:28)
    at L2Q1.main(L2Q1.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: How many times are you calling this function?

Comment: I'm only calling it once!

Comment: Before you call the function, there is a `null` in the array?

Comment: No. All the items in the array are initialized to something other than null.

Comment: Please, edit your post with the [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Comment: Umm...sorry I'm not sure exactly what a stack trace is!! Should I just post all of my code for you? Sorry!!

Comment: The second example you posted doesn't work because `"null"` is an object of a String type, which is completely different from `null`.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the **error**. It's the full message of the exception you get. It is usually in *red* color and contains methods that throws the exception and its line number.

Comment: you might be better off using a List<Student> here.  I'm not sure what all your program does, but it's so much easier to do operations on a List than an object array

Comment: @keenns12 Post how you populate the `students` array.

Comment: There! I posted the whole code and the stack trace! Thanks everyone.

Comment: Student[] is immutable, meaning you can't change the size after you initialized it.  Trying to set it to null, in my opinion, is not good.  I think you would be better off using ArrayList here instead of Object [] since you are tyring to change the size of things around based on things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

You are making elements in your `students` array null. Then you try to use `toString()` but on a `null` element. This is how it looks like: `null.toString()`, obviously that is bad.

---

### Solution Without ArrayList

On the comments people suggested an [**ArrayList**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). I am assuming this is homework and you are forced to use an array, therefore you should do this:

Keep track of the size of the array. Use that to determine how many real elements, non-null elements, you have on the list. Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    // Do something with the array here.
}
```

Make sure you declare `arraySize` as an [**instance variable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable).

```
private int arraySize = 0;
```

Remember you will need to increment `arraySize` for every new element and decrement it every time you null out an element.

Keep in mind that by the time your program finishes your array will have a trail of nulls at the end.

---

### Hackish Solution

In the mean time you can do this to your `printStudents()` -- this is hackish and only a temporary fix.

```
public static void printStudents(Student[] students)
{   
    // Check if the array is null, good practice.   
    if(students == null)
        return;

    System.out.println("Students:");

    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
    {   
        // My hack: Check if element is null, if it is then skip it.
        if(students[i] == null)
            continue;

        System.out.println(students[i].toString());
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is for homework so I do need to keep the array of students. Thanks! The hackish solution will hold for now!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you've already removed some of the students, turning them from `Student` to `null`. You're trying to call `toString()` on one of the non-existing students that are `null`.

I suggest you replace the array with `ArrayList`, from which you can actually remove elements. Alternatively, you can rebuild the array when you remove a student.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a `Student` object at an index to `null`, then later in a different method attempting to call `toString()` on a `null` object.  Using `List` would help you work with this problem much more elegantly.

Without rewriting the whole code, here is how you could implement `List` instead:

```
public static void process() {
  List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
  List<Student> newStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

...
```

Then when you loop through a `List` in all your different functions, you would use

```
  for (int count = 0; count < students.size(); count++) {
    //do stuff here
  }
```

If you want to remove a student from a list, use

```
students.remove(count);
```

To populate the list, use

```
Student student1 = new Student(7654321, "Lara Zhivago", 3.75);
students.add(student1);
....
```